# Project structure issue (MVP): data layer

Tags: android, sqlite, mvp

I write android app using MVP pattern. My question is regarding database layer. I want to make it maximally independent, so it will be possible to replace it with something else without code changing in Presenter in the future. I decided to use pure SQLite without ORM, since the user table is updated in different places with differenet fields (in some place I update user's name, in other place in code - token etc.). ORM (I used realm) doesn't allow to do it, you have to write separate method for updating name, separate - for token etc. 
Another problem is with `ContentValues`: when you update user you have to specify the fields you want to change via `ContentValues` in Presenter, and then Presenter calls `repository.updateUserLocal(contentValues)`, so my Presenter dependents on data layer (if I decided to add ORM to the project, I will need to go to every Presenter and remove `ContentValues`). So the architecture is bad. Can you please advice how to organize the architecture of the app in the best way?

Comment: create a map of values in your presenter and pass that to the model. then have a converter inside your model that changes the map to content values. Also the Presenter should not know about the repository per say, it should just know about a "model" object

Comment: @Blundell thank you, good idea, I upvoted your comment

Comment: @Blundell actually the problem is that I cannot put Object to ContentValues, it accepts String, Byte, Integer etc., but not the Object. And there are differenet types of values in my table, I cannot cast the field to the specific type (some fields are Strings, some - Integers).

Comment: In my opinion presenter should not know anything about how database is implemented.

I would add itnerface which has a method: `updateUser(User)` and then instance of User (model) is passed to reposoitory which translates its fields and saves it somehow in database (it could use ContentValues).

so it is not presenters problem how it is saved

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.